# What is "to the east of the building" called in grammar?

Tags: grammar

> Inverted: To the east of the building is the car park.

Someone said my sentence was wrong. I want to explain to her that the sentence is inverted. I put the bold part ahead. Is the bold part called the adverbial? I put the **adverbial** ahead and therefore the verb should also be put ahead.

> Normal: the car park is **to the east of the building**.

Comment: The person who said it's 'wrong' is herself wrong. 'To the east is a secluded area of the War Memorial and gardens with a mature sycamore backed by a garden copse area of mature trees' - the inversion is a little formal, but that's all.

Comment: In the example I gave above, a careful writer might feel that the long sentence is clearer, more elegant, and easier to comprehend if the information contained in the prepositional phrase is placed at the beginning, rather than at the end following 'is'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bold phrase is a *prepositional phrase*, with "to" as its head. In that sentence, it has an *adverbial* function, so yes, it's an adverbial.

A simple test is to see what question the phrase answers. If it answers a "what" or "who" question, it's probably a *noun phrase*. But if it answers a "when", "where", "why" or "how" question, it's an adverbial. In this case, the question is "where", so the phrase is adverbial.

When we're talking about parts of a sentence, we should refer to phrase types rather than functions, so "*I put the **prepositional phrase** ahead...*" is a more accurate way to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "prepositional phrase," which is a preposition combined with its object and modifiers. Words that are used before a noun to indicate direction, location, or time are prepositions. In this case, "to" is a preposition, indicating the location of the car park in reference to the building.

Comment: But is the prepositional phrase adverbial?

Comment: @gotube it appears so, especially now that I've read your answer ;)